# How to migrate from SQL Server to SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql-server-ce, data-migration

I have created a small database in SQL Server, but want to switch to the Compact edition instead since it is intended for use with a single desktop application. How do I go about migrating to the less advanced system?

Thanks.

[edit]

OK, found an answer in the form of a third-party app, Data Port Wizard.

Also stuff described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/ee665813-54f0-41d8-b0f1-7320ecf58388/

Not sure what I'm going to do when the 30 day license runs out. I'm developing my app for free. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some command line tools: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html and a list of other tools here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html